# SecurityError: The operation is insecure. uploading file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have to update data with input type file (picture) but when the user didn't update the picture an error of security appears i try to fix the problem with this [answer with 21 vote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780959/jquery-javascript-throws-error-the-operation-is-insecure-when-setting-value/12250064#12250064) and i get this in the console `There is an input without a value! <input id="im1" class="dropify-fr" type="file" data-max-file-size="200K" data-default-file="images/formules-v1/thumb/art.jpg" name="photo1">` 
but i don't know how to resolve this problem who have an idea to resolve it?
any help ? thanks

Comment: So you confirmed that this is the same kind of problem as the solution you found... Wich is a solution to identify which input is causing it. Tell us what you did next!

Comment: as i find i can't set a default value for an input with type file(in my case it is a picture), my  issue that how can i allowed  the user to update the other data without updating input file ( for example  updating name , phone and the picture still the same )

Answer (score 1):

From comments below the question:
*«as i find i can't set a default value for an input with type file»*

The thing is that you did not show your code...
**AND**, I never encountered this error, personnaly.
→ So this answer is a guess... Enought sure to post.

**From my understanding** of the answer you cited, The error you have is because you try to change input values programmatically.

Before a submit, I doubt the user can't update/change it's file input value.

But if, for some reason, you need to change any input values **except file** programmatically, like after a form validation that show a modal or something...

You could use this jQuery selector within a condition:

```
$("input").not( ":file" ); // Gives a boolean false on type file, true on everyone else.
```

It would be easier to just return him to the original form.
Just retain the final `submit()` until all answers are correct.


**Now, if you want to change the file input value, it is not possible.**
[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1017237/2159528) clearly states why.