# Javascript - SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have following html element

```
<a class="btn-modal" data-modal-window-id="category-add-modal" href="#" data-mode="edit" data-content="{&quot;category_id&quot;:16,&quot;category_name_en&quot;:&quot;Food&quot;,&quot;category_name_ar&quot;:&quot;\u0637\u0639\u0627\u0645&quot;,&quot;category_icon&quot;:&quot;2c5ee2e6fd0d9f379dd85a55bf66e851.png&quot;}">Edit</a>
```

On click, I want to read the content from `data-content` attribute and populate the corresponding html elememt.

Here is how I tried

```
$('.btn-modal').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-mode') && 'edit' == $(this).attr('data-mode')) {
        var content = $(this).data('content');
        $.each(content, function(id, value) {
            var formElement = $('#'+id);
            formElement.val(value);
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Unfortunately, FF gives me following error

`SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

When I remove this line of code `formElement.val(value);` the error is no more displayed. why is firefox complaining about security issue on me wanting to set the value attribute of an element from JSON?

Any hint on what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was trying to set `val()` to input type file resulting in the error.

This thread helped me understand the issue

[jQuery: Javascript throws Error "The operation is insecure" when setting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780959/jquery-javascript-throws-error-the-operation-is-insecure-when-setting-value)

The issue is fixed now.